# ASP & SQL Server error : Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have done a lot of research on this and tried everything suggested.

I have a column in a SQL Server table called `LotSqFt`. This table is updated with a stored procedure called `sp_EditRecord1`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EditRecord1]
   @LotID      INT,
   @LotSqFt    VARCHAR(16)
AS
    UPDATE Lot 
    SET LotSqFt = @LotSqFt
    WHERE LotID = @LotID
```

I call this procedure from an ASP page and I get the following error:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0cc1'
>   Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
>
> /DTS/engine/processor.asp, line 110
>
> Line 110 is:
>
> Response.Write(oDBc.Errors(0).Description)

Everything I have read says that the name of the column is wrong or doesn't exist. This is not the case for me as I can see the column in query analyzer and retrieve data from it. Is there something else that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that there was a caching issue on the MS-SQL Server instance. Restarting the database server cleared the issue and solved the problem.

Comment: Always a bummer when problems are solved this way. But good for you OP! At least we learned that restarting a database _may_ solve all your problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred on a *Classic ASP VBScript* line attempting to use the stored procedure parameters that should be retrieved when performing a `.Parameters.Refresh`, for example:

```
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn 
cmd.CommandText = "your-stored-procedure-name-here"
' Response.Write ( "cmd.CommandText: " & cmd.CommandText & "<br />" & vbCrLf )
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandTimeout = 900 
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
' Response.Write ( "cmd.Parameters.Count: " & cmd.Parameters.Count & "<br />" & vbCrLf )
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = MyValue
```

Make sure permissions to execute stored procedures are set up properly. Worked for me. I lost permissions after doing a database restore:

```
USE <database> ;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON stored-procedure TO user
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless you return a recordset with a "SELECT" statement, you won't have a database object to iterate through.

Comment: This is just an update and requires no select for returned data.